# How to find data of object xpath

Tags: html, object, url, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to find the data of a object on a website using xpath but it wont recognize object.

I am using this which works for divs but it wont output anything but {} when trying to find objects.

```
response.xpath("//object").extract()
```

This is the object I am trying to extract data form (I need the url)

```
<object id="swfobject_embed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://uploads.ungrounded.net/575000/575163_Superfighters.swf?123" style="visibility: visible;" width="800" height="600"><param name="wmode" value="direct"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="never"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowfullscreeninteractive" value="true"><param name="flashvars" value="NewgroundsAPI_PublisherID=1&amp;NewgroundsAPI_SandboxID=5be5746a96d56&amp;NewgroundsAPI_SessionID=&amp;NewgroundsAPI_UserName=&amp;lt;deleted&amp;gt;&amp;NewgroundsAPI_UserID=0&amp;ng_username=&amp;lt;deleted&amp;gt;"></object>
```

Comment: If `//object` returns nothing, then obviously there is no `object` in page source. Can you share page URL?

Comment: @Andersson I am trying to get the swf files for games on Newgrounds. I was using this game to test https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/575163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `<object>` node in page source - it's generated dynamically by JavaScript. You can directly parse JavaScript function to get required swf-file URL:

```
import requests
import re

response =  requests.get('https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/575163').text
swf_url = re.search('swfobject.embedSWF\("(.+?)",', r).group(1)
print(swf_url)

# https://uploads.ungrounded.net/575000/575163_Superfighters.swf?123
```